# How to set property in code for a datagrid template column

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid template column that uses a DatePicker in the cell editing template:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn
    Header="Date Paid"
    DisplayIndex="2"
    Width="100">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Path=DatePaid, Converter={StaticResource conDate}, StringFormat='MMM d, yyyy'}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DatePicker
                SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DatePaid}">
            </DatePicker>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I want to set some properties in code for this DatePicker.  I know the column is not in the visual tree so how do I reference the DatePicker in code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know the column is not in the visual tree so how do I reference the DatePicker in code behind?

You don't. In fact there is no single `DatePicker` to reference because there will be a `DatePicker` element created for each row in the `DataGrid`.

If you want to set some default properties for all of these, you could use a `Style`:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DatePickerStyle" TargetType="DatePicker">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
            <!--set the properties here...-->
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <DataGrid ..>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            ...
            <DataGridTemplateColumn
                Header="Date Paid"
                DisplayIndex="2"
                Width="100">
                ...
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DatePaid}" Style="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I have marked this as the answer but it has two defects that I'd like to correct.  First, when setting the DisplayStartDate in the style, I can only set it to a fixed date or today.  I'd like to be able to set it to some arbitrary date such as the first day of the current month.

Comment: Second, it does not work for rows that already exist but that the DatePicker is used to set a column value that is blank in a currently existing row.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `DataGrid` `PreparingCellForEdit` event, and use `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild` to locate your `DatePicker` like so:

```
 private void Dg_OnPreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
    {
        var dp= VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(e.EditingElement, 0) as DatePicker;
    }
```

xaml:

```
<DataGrid PreparingCellForEdit="Dg_OnPreparingCellForEdit" ..>
..
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: That works but ... well, I don't mean to be ungrateful but that sets the desired properties for the DatePicker each time the user enters a cell in the column.  What I'd like to do is set the DatePicker's properties in the Window_Load event and be done with it for the lifetime of the window.  Possible?

Comment: @SezMe I don't thing that would be possible in the Window_Load event since the DatePicker will be reinstantiated each time you edit a cell, applying a style as mm8 suggested could be a better solution in your case.